# How to hardcode date in oracle query using python

Tags: sql, oracle

how do the hardcode date in Oracle query using Python?

```
query1 = """ SELECT * FROM employees WHERE HIRE_DATE = '2006, 9, 28'"""  
cursor.execute(query)
```

please guide me
many thanks for considering my request.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python. See [Datetime Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1)

Answer (score 4):

Use date literal:

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE HIRE_DATE = date '2026-09-28'
```

or `to_date` function with appropriate format mask:

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE HIRE_DATE = to_date('2006-09-28', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```